# What am I doing wrong with this Python regex that is supposed to match repeats of a pattern, followed by an optional pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Here is what I am trying:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'(?P<label>(?:[^_]+)+)(_r(?P<repeat_num>\d+))?')

def main():
    s1 = 'abc_123'
    s2 = 'abc_123_r1'

    m1 = r.match(s1)
    m2 = r.match(s2)

    print(m1.groups())
    print(m2.groups())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am expecting the first string `s1` to match `abc_123` for the `label` group and nothing for `repeat_num`.

And I am expecting the second string `s2` to match `abc_123` for the `label` group and '1' for `repeat_num`.

The actual result stops at `abc` in both cases.

Comment: Note that `(?:[^_]+)+` should actually be `[^_]+`. There is no point quantifying it unless you add `_?` at the start. Then, it will be rather inefficient. Try [`(?P<label>[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*?)(_r(?P<repeat_num>\d+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/M8sPFH/1/) to solve your issue.

Comment: try this: r = re.compile(r'(?P<label>(?:[^_]+)_\d+)(_r(?P<repeat_num>\d+))?')

Comment: You're telling it to stop at the first underscore. It then _optionally_ matches the `_r` part which is after the `_123` in the text. The result is it only matches _abc_. Do you want to fix it?

Comment: Thanks @Sphinx, that technically does work for this example, but abc_123 was just an example. Really, there are an arbitrary number of strings separated by underscores.

Comment: This is a similar problem to trying to parse a filename and check a suffix when it has periods in it. Consider "my.file.name.txt" v.s. "my.file.name" v.s. "my.filename.txt". In that case we might want a regex that says "Is there a three-letter suffix? If so, add it to a group."

Comment: In the meantime, I have this solved by splitting on on the underscores and evaluating the final element of the returned array to look for `r\d+`. But I would like to find a reasonable way to do it via regex so that it can be configurable.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's partially due to the `[^_]` bit, which matches "any character except underscore".

I couldn't immediately figure out a solution that would properly capture these tokens; I highly recommend using [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to play with your regular expression in order to figure out how to match the pieces correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is not matching the `_` between the `abc` and `123` pieces of your input strings. You need to modify your first capturing group in order to be able to handle those.

A direct translation though may run into difficulties, because it's a bit difficult to distinguish the last `_r1` block from a normal extra block like `_123`. I think the pattern below does it correctly, but you should double check that it always does what you expect:

```
(?P<label>[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*?)(?:_r(?P<repeat_num>\d+))?
```

If you always require at least two underlined separated groups in the first part of the text (e.g. `abc_123`, but never just `abc` or `123` by itself), you should replace the `*?` with `+?`.

Comment: Thank you. That did not work, but I appreciate the suggestions.